# IE11 button text overflowing button, should be expanding button width and moving to new row if too big

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Title pretty much explains the issue. In every other browser except IE11, the buttons fit to the width of the inner text. It then moves the button to a new row if it is too big to fit on the current row and auto expands the other buttons to fill the entire row.

[image]

I have tried several things with various `flex` properties, but can't resolve the issue. Other browsers basically work with Bootstrap 4 out of the box.

Comment: Have you tried `whitespace`-property?

Comment: Hi, yes. `white-space: normal` is the only one that affected it, but it made the text wrap, changing the height of the button, and looking just awful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to reproduce your issue but on my side on IE, the button will automatically move to a new row when the button text is too big on IE11.

Or you could {display: flex;flex-direction: row;} to enforce the button to display row by row.

Here is my test code and output:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .BtnSize {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    }
</style>
<body>
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
  <input type="button" value="Test1Test1Test1,Test2Test2Test2" class="BtnSize" />
</body>
```

[image: the result without setting flex]
  [image: the result with setting flex]